# ¿Cómo modifico el código fuente de un comando de la terminal de linux?

Tags: c, linux, compilar

¿Cómo puedo modificar el archivo del comando ls (ls.c) para cambiar el -help de texto en ingles a texto en español?

He modificado el texto en el archivo .c pero al momento de compilar hay muchos errores que no sé como solucionar, alguien sabe como hacerlo de manera correcta?

Comment: Tu distribución debería proveerte de páginas de manual traducidas al idioma seleccionado como idioma de sistema. Si has modificado el código de `ls`, cosa que no recomendaría solo por conseguir una traducción, y te saltan errores de compilación, deberías compartir el código de las modificaciones y los errores del compilador, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Esta pregunta parece ser el típico [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY). Tu problema original es que quieres que el texto de ayuda del comando `ls` se muestre en español, intuyes que la solución es modificar el código fuente y compilar pero tampoco sabes cómo hacerlo, y en vez de preguntar sobre el problema original preguntas cómo implementar la solución que ideaste. Cuando pidas ayuda, sobretodo en foros de internet, recuerda enfocarte en tu problema original y no caer en el problema XY, de lo contrario dificultas a los demás el poder darte una respuesta apropiada.

Answer (score 0):

**Nota:** En base a mi comentario anterior, esta respuesta aborda el problema original sobre cómo mostrar el texto de ayuda del comando `ls` en español.

---

Linux y los sistemas Unix en general dan soporte a lo que se conoce como **configuración regional** (*locale* en inglés), la cual se encarga de adaptar varios aspectos del sistema (codificación de caracteres, representación numérica y monetaria, idioma de las aplicaciones, etc.) al país e idioma del usuario en cuestión.

La configuración se establece mediante diversas variables de entorno (revisa los manuales [*locale(7)*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) y [*locale(5)*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/locale.5.html) para más información). La que se encarga del idioma en el cual serán mostrados los mensajes de los comandos es `LC_MESSAGES`.

Para cambiar la configuración regional de un comando necesitas asegurarte de varias cosas:

1. Revisa que el comando en cuestión soporte la configuración regional del usuario.
2. Verifica que la configuración regional deseada esté instalada y configurada correctamente.
3. Cambia la configuración regional a la deseada.

Puedes cambiar la configuración regional de dos maneras:

1. **Permanentemente:** añadiendo `LC_MESSAGES=valor; export LC_MESSAGES` a algún archivo de inicialización de la shell, como `/etc/profile` o `${HOME}/.profile`
2. **Temporalmente:** añadiendo `LC_MESSAGES=valor` antes del nombre del comando (`LC_MESSAGES=valor comando`) o ejecutando dicho comando a través de `env` (`env LC_MESSAGES=valor comando`).

En tu caso, necesitas una configuración regional en español. Revisa cuáles tienes instaladas con el comando `locale -a | grep '^es_'`:

```
$ locale -a | grep '^es_'
es_AR.utf8
es_BO.utf8
es_CL.utf8
es_CO.utf8
es_CR.utf8
es_CU
es_CU.utf8
es_DO.utf8
es_EC.utf8
es_ES.utf8
es_GT.utf8
es_HN.utf8
es_MX.utf8
es_NI.utf8
es_PA.utf8
es_PE.utf8
es_PR.utf8
es_PY.utf8
es_SV.utf8
es_US.utf8
es_UY.utf8
es_VE.utf8
```

Elige la que prefieras y aplícala:

```
$ LC_MESSAGES='es_MX.utf8' ls --help
Modo de empleo: ls [OPCIÓN]... [FICHERO]...
Muestra información acerca de los FICHEROs (del directorio actual por defecto).
Ordena las entradas alfabéticamente si no se especifica ninguna de las
opciones -cftuvSUX ni --sort.
...
```